# How do I capture all error & display an error message

Tags: python

In my python code, I would like to catch all the errors & display an error message. For example, I would like to do this thing

```
try:
    my code block
catch:
    print("Error:x error occurred" )
```

Can you suggest me how to do this?

Comment: did it work? what error did you get? Please, post something minimmal but ready to paste into the python interactive shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in the exception type, then you can catch all exceptions using `except Exception as ex` (`ex` can be anything), and then get the exception type using `type(ex).__name__`:

```
try:
  # example, dividing by zero
  x = 1 / 0
except Exception as ex:
  print("Error: {} error occurred".format(type(ex).__name__))
```

Output:

```
Error: ZeroDivisionError error occurred
```

If the type doesn't matter, then this will do:

```
try:
  # some code
except:
  print("Error:an error occurred") # any error, but you don't know which
```